# res.write() writes the data all at once rather than in chunks

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs, streaming

I am creating a streaming endpoint where the data that I am pulling from another stream (axios request) is being pushed to the response stream by using res.write() method. The problem is the res.write() placed inside .on() is not writing anything to response stream.

```
const stream = await axios({
    method: "get",
    url: "http://localhost:8000/api/home/stream",
    responseType: "stream",
  });

  stream.data.on('data', (data)=> {
    res.write(data.toString());
    console.log(data.toString());
  });

  stream.data.on('end', () => {
    res.end();
    console.log('steam ended')
  })
```

Tried using the pipe method but it also sends the data after the event "end" is emitted.

Comment: could be because your streaming data is smaller than the chunk sizes from the server. then it all comes with one chunk.